# What file determines “# Registers:” entries in /home/ubuntu/.viminfo after apache2 restart

Tags: ubuntu, apache-httpd, http-proxy

I posted this question in "Ask Ubuntu" but no replies.

I have installed Apache2 on Ubuntu LTS 16.04.  I looked at the /home/ubuntu/.viminfo file and it contained the following lines.

```
# Registers:
"0      LINE    0
      ProxyPass /app/ http://10.0.1.7/
"1      LINE    0
    ProxyPass /app1/ http://10.0.1.27/
"2      LINE    0
    ProxyPass /app1/ http://10.0.1.27/
"3      LINE    0
    ProxyPass /app1/ http://10.0.1.27/
""-     CHAR    0
    2
```

I changed the 10.0.1.27 entries to 10.0.1.7 but running

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

changes them back to 10.0.1.27.  (I no longer have a server with the private IP 10.0.1.27.)

There is clearly some configuration file that sets

```
ProxyPass /app1/ http://10.0.1.27/
```

when

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

is called but I was unable to find anything, along those lines, in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf or in /etc/apache2/httpd.conf or by calling

```
sudo grep app1 /etc/apache2/*.*
```

Comment: @icarus Why are you asking me?

Comment: @icarus Kindly please stop bothering me. I did not review your suggested edit and have no interest in answering your concerns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `~/.viminfo` file for a user (in this case `ubuntu`) contains various bits of information to persist state for the `vim` editor between runs. `vi` and `vim` have `registers` which are used to store things, the registers with numeric names 1 through 9 form a stack. If you have vim then `:help quote_number` should tell you about them.

**The upshot of all this is that if you edit this file using vim, and then exit it, this file will be regenerated with the current stack of registers.**

This is almost certainly nothing to do with the `sudo apache restart`.

Comment: You are absolutely right.  I never would have expected that.  Thanks very much,